# Replace underscore with space and upper case first character in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array.

```
$state = array("gujarat","andhra_pradesh","madhya_pradesh","uttar_pradesh");
```

**Expected Output**

```
$state = array("Gujarat","Andhra Pradesh","Madhya Pradesh","Uttar Pradesh");
```

I want to convert array values with each first character of a word with `UpperCase` and replace <kbd>_</kbd> with <kbd>space</kbd>. So I do it using this loop and it working as expected.

```
foreach($states as &$state)
 {
    $state = str_replace("_"," ",$state);
    $state = ucwords($state);
 }
```

But my question is: is there any PHP function to convert the whole array as per my requirement?

Comment: create a string replacement function, the `array_map` it is another way. you said its working fine, why the change?

Comment: @Ghost It working find with `foreach` loop but I want `short` code to implement it

Comment: oh okay, sure, those answers below should suffice

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the `array_map` function.

```
function modify($str) {
    return ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $str));
}
```

Then in just use the above function as follows:

```
$states=array_map("modify", $old_states)
```

Comment: Fulfilled my purpose. But any idea how to use it in the controller in Codeigniter OOPS ? $this->functionname() ?

Answer (score 4):

Need to use `array_map` function like as

```
$state = array("gujarat","andhra_pradesh","madhya_pradesh","uttar_pradesh");
$state = array_map(upper, $state);
function upper($state){
    return str_replace('_', ' ', ucwords($state));
}
print_r($state);// output Array ( [0] => Gujarat [1] => Andhra pradesh [2] => Madhya pradesh [3] => Uttar pradesh )
```

Comment: Your code also `short` and `sweet` but you are late. Thanks

Comment: Its ok you like it thats enough.. Happy Coding

Comment: This code has syntax typos.

Answer (score 2):

[PHP's array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can apply a callback method to each element of an array:

```
$state = array_map('makePretty', $state);

function makePretty($value) 
{
    $value= str_replace("_"," ",$value);
    return ucwords($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_map()` function

```
<?php
    function fun($s)
    {
        $val = str_replace("_"," ",$s);
        return ucwords($val);
    }
    $state = array("gujarat","andhra_pradesh","madhya_pradesh","uttar_pradesh");
    $result = array_map('fun',$state);
    print_r($result);
?>
```